# Use of callback in skipToNext() method with Spotify API

Tags: java, android, spotify

I'm working on a application for Android using Spotify API. I'm currently working on the music player where i have a "play/pause" button and a "next track" button. I have some trouble with the methods - skipToNext(Player.OperationCallback callback). The play/pause method looks the same and also has a callback as parameter. 
I do not entirely understand that parameter so i used (null) for the play/pause function. That works fine in that case but when i send in null for the skipToNext() it doesnt work.
Can someone help me on this?

https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/player/com/spotify/sdk/android/player/SpotifyPlayer.html#skipToNext-com.spotify.sdk.android.player.Player.OperationCallback-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to pass an implementor of callback. So just make a class implementing Player.OperationCallback and do something inside the methods:

```
void    onError(Error error) 
void    onSuccess()
```

For the time being just log what happened. 
Don't pass null because if the code inside the API is not checking nullability you will have problems.

So. Create a class such as:

```
 public class MyPlayerCallback implements Player.OperationCallback {
     public void onSuccess() {
          //log here
     }
     public void onError(Error error) {
           // log here
     }
 }
```

Create an instance whenever you need it

```
   MyClientCallback callback = new MyClientCallback();
```

and just use it

```
  skipToNext(callback);
```